# Redirect if the file not included

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried many codes but none of them worked. Is there any way to redirect with htaccess if the file is not included by PHP.

htaccess so far:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2 [QSA,L]
```

So when i write any `/en/introduction.html` it will be rewrited.
But when someone want to get one of my php codes (e.g. `/menu.php`) that should be redirected to `/index.php`.

In PHP I can solve it with a begining PHP code, but I slows the system, that's why I want htaccess.

Comment: This rule will only redirect `.html` files.

Comment: "RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html" means: Do the rewrite if the url ends with .html. You can do the same for .php also. Group together by changing the html to (html|php)

Comment: "I've tried many codes" Stop guessing, start reading and learning…

Comment: "Redirect if file is not included" needs a programming language which .htaccess is not made for.

Comment: I know what it means, it write all non-exist `html` files to my `index.php` that loads the languages, the head and the body. In the body section I include `menu.php` that writes `ul`s and `li`s getting its data from MySQL. I want nobody to see my `menu.php` only from included in `index.php`. If I rewrite my `menu.php` it can't be included, but if I not they can see it without other parts of the page.

Comment: @androbin: You don't want anyone to directly use `/menu.php` link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

What this will do is, if a file exists in your server, for example `/en/introduction.html` it will load that file. This applies to folders and links.

All other requests are then forwarded into `index.php`

Now, within `index.php` you can use the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and parse the URL structure and do what you want.

---

As for disabling direct access to `menu.php` ...

Add this line to your **index.php** after `<?php` tag:

```
define('_IN_SCRIPT_)', true);
```

Now, add this line to **menu.php** after `<?php` tag

```
if (!defined('_IN_SCRIPT_') || !_IN_SCRIPT_) {
    exit('Direct access not allowed.');
}
```

Now, when you include menu.php in index.php, the script will work. if someone accessed menu.php directly in browser, they will get the error.

Comment: Thank you, is define better that use simply `$inscript`?

Comment: [define()](http://uk3.php.net/define) functions defines a named constant at runtime. I prefer constants than variables for tasks like these. If you had to use variable and then load it in a function, then you'd have to use `global $inscript` before you could use it in the function. Using constants (which are globally accessible through all your scripts) is easier.

Answer (score 0):

So it can't be solved with htaccess only with PHP.
Thank you!